# Reload annotations in MKmapView from another tabbed view

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I'm building an iOS app with two tabbed views. The first tabbed view has a small function which allows user to update data. The data along with CLLocation is collected and stored in a SQLite dB. The second view consists of a mapView which then drops pins using annotations on a map.

I'm unable to reload annotations as soon as some data is being added to the first tabbed view. How can I get a pointer to the second tabbed view controller which has the mapview. I already have the reloadAnnotations method written in the second view controller.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Why don't you use an NSNotification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, easiest options:

- Get reference to the other view controller and call reloadAnnotations. You can get the reference to the other view controller by accessing the right element from the array that you get by calling `self.tabBarController.viewControllers`. Then you can cast this to your view controller and call your `reloadAnnotations` method.
- Use `NSNotification` and listen to that notification on the first tabbar.

Comment: Thank you Kind sir. 
[[self.navigationController.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]refreshAnnotations]; This helped me to be more accurate.